# Display Data in a table win form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I need to present data in a tabular form in windows form using c#. Basically, I will extract data from received messages (not database) then display it in a table by specifying the column and row.

First, I started with `TableLayoutPanel` but I discovered that I should add controls for each cell which is not what I need and it is tedious.

Do you have any better suggestion? Much appreciated.

Comment: Either a DataGridview or a ListView can do this for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're best off using a `DataGridView`, see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx).

It allows you to assign a datasource (which you can specify yourself). The image below demonstrates one of many ways that you can make your dataview look like.

[image]

There is even a nice tutorial which you can follow [right here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial).